# How can i put my taskbar to be always on top?

Tags: python, tkinter, taskbar

I want to place my menubar frame to the top of the window like the tkinter's Menu module.

```
class My_Menu:
    def __init__(self, master, name="Default", expand="full", mode="bar"):
        ##### create the frame #####
        self.menus = {}

        self.master = master
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)

        self.master_frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.master_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
        self.master_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.master_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.main_frame = Frame(self.master_frame)
        self.main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
        self.main_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
```

Comment: I am pretty sure You already asked this question once at least.

Comment: How are you using `My_Menu`? Can you gives us a complete example please?

Comment: I could only suggest inheriting from frame and use `.place()` or maybe other layout methods will do fine, but a frame will help a lot (multiples, one for the menu, one for the rest of the widgets).

Comment: I honestly am not sure, if this is possible. But you can `root.grid_rowconfigure` and add extra space to the first column, so the other items inserted looks normal(??).

Comment: why don't You just create a menu using tkinter's `Menu`? or if You want to have tabs try using tkinter.ttk's `Notebook`

Comment: @Matiiss yes i've already asked this question today but it closed automatically when i insert the full code. I had to write more details.

Comment: @TheLizzard its not the full code just the init method.

Comment: @pixelshash Can you please show us how you create your `My_Menu` object? Is it in its own window? Is it inside a frame that doesn't move? Is it a frame that is placed at the location where the user presses the mouse?

Comment: @Matiiss I want to create my own menubar with some new function. And it works well, the problem is in the placement. But yeah i think i will solve this with the .place() method.

Comment: @TheLizzard https://ibb.co/XF2v4yn

Comment: https://ibb.co/ZBCzLSG its working fine but when i try to grid a widget to the first row/column then it wont shown because the menubar frame is in that place.

Comment: i want to avoid this that when i try to grid a widget to the firs row/column then the menubar's frame go to the grid(row=-1, column=-1) . For example.

Comment: @pixelshash Well why don't you just add 1 to all of the `row` values when you are gridding other widgets? The only way I can think of is to create your own `Tk` class that can handle the menu.

Comment: @TheLizzard After all i will do this.I just wanted to know if there is a simple solution for this. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: The simple way is already mentioned in a comment of your closed question, use two frames.  One for the menu, one for other widgets.

Comment: @acw1668 yes i've already used a frame for the menu. I just want to know if there is another solution.

Comment: Its annoying that there isnt maxsize option for grid..

Comment: Do i need to add an extra space to the column? What do you think? @CoolCloud

Comment: sorry i missed your comment yesterday

Comment: I do not have a solution with your class, but if you want, I can make a solution with two buttons inside a frame, but still you will have to add an option `sticky`.

Comment: Just to confirm, where you the same person that asked how to keep the menubar on top of GUI having 2 buttons? That question is not found, and I am referring to it.

Comment: Yes i'm that person. https://ibb.co/k587NHQ

Comment: Well, if you make a solution with your own frame, its ok.

Comment: I just want to set a maxsize for the menubar without any affect for other widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is any way to do this, but a way around will be to create space to the row and use `sticky` to put the menu on top always.

```
from tkinter import *

class MenuFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,*args,**kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent,*args,**kwargs)

        self.b1 = Button(self,text='File',width=50)
        self.b1.grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.b2 = Button(self,text='Help',width=50)
        self.b2.grid(row=0,column=1)

    def ret_max(self):
        self.update()
        return self.b1.winfo_height()


root = Tk()

menu = MenuFrame(root)
menu.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='n') # Can move this line in or out of class

height = menu.ret_max()
root.grid_rowconfigure(0,pad=height) # Make it have extra space of height of button

Button(root,text='Dummy Button').grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='s')

root.mainloop()
```